# Promise timing not as expected

Tags: node.js, promise

I have to do a function that will delete an array of IDs from a mongo dates with mongoose. But the promise is not working => not waiting.

```
async function deleteTestCases(testcases){

    await Promise.all(testcases.map( (entryMain) => {

        Case
            .findById(entryMain)
            .exec()
            .then(function(tcafe) {
                console.log(tcafe.use);
                tcafe.use = "false";
                tcafe.save()
                    .then(tCase => {
                        console.log("Tcase Update done");
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));

            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }));

};
```

testcases is an array of ObjectIds from mongoose query. Then I go through this array with promise.all and map. As I understood, Mongoose exec() is a promise.

I call this out of a get function:

```
router.post('/deletecase', async (req, res) => {

    await deleteTestCases(req.body.selection).then(res => {

        console.log("delete Ok");

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("delete fehler");

    });

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The problem I have, this is working. The items are updated at all. But the order of the call is wrong. The order I got is

- delete Ok
- true
- Tcase Update done

But I expected

- true
- Tcase Update done
- delete Ok

Maybe I miss some await in the code?

Comment: Your `testcases.map( (entryMain) => {` doesn't `return` anything, hence you give `Promise.all` an array of `undefined`, hence why `Promise.all` doesn't wait, since there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: Btw, try to avoid mixing `then` with `await` style.

Comment: In addition to what @VLAZ said, you also forgot to `return` the `tcafe.save().…` promise from the `then` callback, so your outer promise chain would have ignored it.

Comment: maybe you can give me an example what I missed? Because if I return the functions, nothing will change.

Comment: This is a familiar old story of missing returns (and swallowed errors).